# Satis build tells that Authentication failed

Tags: package, composer-php, satis

I am preparing private package repository using satis. We are using git for versioning our source code. When I use credentials in repository address everything works well, packages.json is where it should be with proper content. But when I remove these credentials and try to build packages.json via

```
php bin/satis build config.json web/
```

I get

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

which is understandable. I want to ask is there any other to authenticate to git repo from satis without keeping plain credentails in packages.json? I only add that I can't access repositories via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have to use .netrc file and store my credentials there. Everything works like music now.

Comment: Just for the record, if you update the satis vendors (and hence get one of the recent composer) it should prompt you for a login/password.

Comment: Any chance you can tell me what "credentials" (ie the parameters) you have to use to add authentication? or what the .netrc file is and what it needs to contain?